# Регулярное выражение, для удаления всего, кроме даты

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть набор строк, где помимо даты еще накидано всякого мусора.
На пример

- 01.03.2017 (some garbage № BP-26/17
- ```
        21.12.2017 info
  ```

и т.д.
Строка не всегда начинается с даты. Там могут быть табы, пробелы, перевод стоки, неразделяющий пробел и т.д
Надо удалить все, кроме даты.  Саму дату выловить нетрудно: (\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}). А как сделать отрицание не для набора символов, а для шаблона?

Comment: Зачем удалять всё кроме? *Найдите* дату, у вас же есть шаблон, `\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}`

Comment: @Deimon [`~.*(\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}).*~`](https://regex101.com/r/31fUKU/1)

Answer (score 1):

Решение задачи средствами php:

```
<?php
$str = "      10.12.2017 info";
if (preg_match("/^[\D]*\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}/", $str)) {
    echo "Вхождение найдено.";
} else {
    echo "Вхождение не найдено.";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

В [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) можно использовать `s///`:

```
perl -E '$str="      21.12.2017 info"; $str=~s/.*(\d{2}\.\d{2}.\d{4}).*/$1/; say $str'
21.12.2017
```

Comment: лучше `$str=~ m/.*(\d{2}\.\d{2}.\d{4}).*/; say $1;`

Comment: @nörbörnën ответил на заданный вопрос.